# Making a text into a list without including certain variables

Tags: python

I am given a problem where I have to open a text file and then make it a list. This is the text file:

```
Ronald,               80,       182
Ethan L,   73,       175
```

Firstly I will open it:

```
def function():
    text =('users.txt','r')
    text.read().# this is where I want to filter away all the spaces and ','
    return text
```

This problem is very advanced, is there any way I can use the python functions or will I have to import something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst the accepted answer works, it is neither very pythonic nor very efficient.  Here is a better way:

```py
def read_lines(fn):
    result = []
    with open(fn) as f:
        for line in f:
            result.append([x.strip() for x in line.split(",")])

    return result
```

Optimisations:

- Iterate the file directly, rather than reading it all into ram and then splitting (thus saving ram)
- avoid using `list(map(` where a listcomp is clearer and easier
- avoid the overhead of calling a function just to strip

for the fun of it I took the filename as a parameter, because presumably there's some reason to wrap this in a function.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def function():
    result = []

    with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
        raw_txt = file.read()  # this is where I want to filter away all the spaces and ','

    lines = raw_txt.splitlines()

    for line in lines:
        result.append(list(map(lambda e: e.strip(), line.split(","))))
    

    return result
```